# Recognize roman numeral followed by '.', space and then capital letter. (RegEx)

Tags: python, regex, python-re, roman-numerals

Can someone please help me with this?

I'm trying to match roman numerals with a "." at the end and then a space and a capital letter after the point. For example:

I. And here is a line.

II. And here is another line.

X. Here is again another line.

So, the regex should match the `"I. A"`, `"II. A"` and `"X. H"`.

I did this `"^(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}){1,4}\.\s[A-Z]"` But the problem is that this RegEx is also matching with `". A"` and i don't want it.

In resume it should have at least one roman numeral, followed by a `"."` and then a space and a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `(?=[LXVI])` lookahead at the start that would require at least one Roman number letter at the start of the string:

```
^(?=[LXVI])(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\.\s[A-Z]
# ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MsAtZQ/2). Not sure why you used `{1,4}`, I suggest removing it.

Another workaround here would be to use a word boundary right after `^`:

```
^\b(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\.\s[A-Z]
#^^
```

This would disallow a match where `.` appears at the start since `\b`, required at the same position as the start of string, requires that the next char must be a word char (and here, it must be a Roman number).

Regarding `\.\s[A-Z]`, you may enhance it you add `+` or `*` after `\s`, and if you ever need to match it and exclude from a match, turn it into a positive lookahead, `(?=\.\s+[A-Z])` or `(?=\.\s*[A-Z])`.

Comment: Awwwwesome!!!! It worked!! Thank you very much for your help and the perfect explanation.